# Cordova: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///

Tags: cordova, quasar-framework, quasar

Cordova build running on Quasar is giving error

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///data....
```

Added below to the config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="file:///*" />
<access origin="file:///*" />
```

Also added the content-security-policy in index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *; img-src * filesystem: file:">
```

Comment: Looks like an extra slash in the URI.

Comment: ImgCache library is giving me three slashes only!

Comment: Can you add some code example of what is failing?

Answer (score -2):

this is due to some url be it image or configuration file is being used incorrectly for example

```
<image src = "/ logo.png" />
```

which is wrong and it should be so

```
<image src = ". logo.png" />
```

On the web it is not affected but on mobile it is.

check your layout and pages, especially App.vue in case you use preFetch

https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/handling-assets